# Are players allowed to pass a penalty kick?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

I saw a video of Johann Cruyff [passing a penalty kick](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=909394135872786&set=vb.338233632988842&type=2&theater), isn't that against the rules?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Law 14 in the IFAB laws of the game](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure):

- The ball must be kicked forward
- The penalty taker cannot touch the ball until another player has touched it
- No player from either team (other than the goalie and the penalty taker) can enter the penalty area or penalty arc until the ball is kicked

Assuming Cruyff's teammate didn't enter the penalty area until after the ball was kicked and moving forward, the move is legal. Although I should point out that the link below (and my points above) are for the current Laws of the Game. The linked video is from 1982, so it's possible things were different then, though I don't think the rules for a penalty kick have changed that much in the past 30 years.

Rules for a penalty shoot-out (at the end of a tied match where you need a winner) are quite different.

Comment: This can go very badly wrong. A famous example is when Henry and Pires tried this once for Arsenal. Pires didn't make enough contact with the ball and Henry didn't know if it had been kicked yet. They both got confused and the other team were able to clear it.